# same column name but the data is from other table

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm having a problem on a query because I cannot get how to do this.

These are my tables:

[image]

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: I attached an image for the table, Please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's alternate solution:

```
select time_out, time_in,
       (select employee_name from table_employee where emp_no = tb.tagged_by) tagged_by,
       (select employee_name from table_employee where emp_no = tb.untagged_by) untagged_by,
from table_breaktime tb
```

Comment: @Jasmin Accept the answer if it solved your probem :)

Comment: Yes, this answer does. Thank you. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at standard MySQL documentation for [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```
select timeout, 
       timein, 
       taggedby.employee_name tagged_by,
       untaggedby.employee_name untagged_by 
  from table_breaktime tb
  JOIN table_employee taggedby on taggedby.emp_no = tb.tagged_by
  JOIN table_employee untaggedbyon untaggedby.emp_no = tb.untagged_by
```

We are joining the employee table twice, on the columns `tagged_by` and `untagged_by` from the table `table_breaktime`. To fetch the employee names individually

Comment: You might want to add aliases to columns :)